# Rest Framework for Django and Token Authentication confusion

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

**Question Background**

Hello, I'm having some issues figuring out how to integrate auth tokens into my application. 
Currently, I have everything setup as per the docs (at least I think so, see point 1 on documents I've looked over).  I can reach the auth token endpoint and in fact get a token, I can also verify that it is allowing me to authenticate with that token as I have it added to the required permissions of some of my endpoints (provided below).

**Core question**

My question is, I'm trying to figure out how to associate a user's post with their auth token and make them the 'owner' of that post with their token but use their 'username' instead of their 'token' string.  I appreciate any and all help :)

In my models.py file...I get the error that the owner must be an instance of 'User' and I'm assuming it's from the Django auth.User.  I'm wondering how I can change this so that it uses the token to figure out who the user is and save it as their name.  I've looked over the documentation and I'm not sure where I can find it.

**The documents I've looked over**

1. rest framework [authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication)

As I've stated previously, I can authenticate with my tokens just fine with this line of code in my views....and it works just fine, no errors. Which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong with my model.py (pasted in below).

`authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
# Create your models here.
class PRequests(models.Model):
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='p_requests')
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  pmessage = models.TextField()
  approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(PRequests, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'api',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'wlmapp',
'p_requests',
'corsheaders',
'nuggets',
)
```

I have added the authtoken to framework and included an endpoint so users can actually receive a token.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation of the problem it seems I did everything correctly except I had to purge the database (delete the database) in order for the tokens to do correctly.  The migrations did not work unfortunately.

Steps to get working:
1. Delete the local sql lite database
2. recreate data base
3. get my token
4. resume normal operations and everything works nicely now :)